# Relation between chi-squared statistic scores and classification accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, chi-squared-test, feature-selection, supervised-learning

I am evaluating the utility of two distinct sets of features for solving a given  supervised classification problem with two classes. I am using the chi-squared statistic as a feature selection mechanism (will drop features with score 0) and RandomForest algorithm as my classifier.

My first set has ~10 features and the chi-squared scores of the top 5 are below:

```
55.999   feature1
45.862   feature2
45.862   feature3
32.374   feature4 
18.297   feature5
```

When I classify with these features with Randomforests , I get an accuracy of 84.2% and ROC area of 0.89.

My second set of features are ~100 in number and are distinct from my first set. The chi-squared scores of these features are much higher (over 10 of them have high scores like the scores shown below)

```
112.0761   feature0a
 86.6586   feature0b
 86.0575   feature0c
 85.3446   feature0d
 84.2301   feature0e
```

When I perform classification with this set of features with the Randomforest classifier. I am somehow getting worse performance than the other set.. with an accuracy of 74.86% and ROC area of 0.77. I am not sure how this is possible and wondering how this can be explained? Isn't the second set supposed to perform better?